# Jquery using different approaches for accessing elements value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Both do the same thing. However the method 2 looks cleaner. What's their difference at all if both return the same values? Which is more efficient?

```js
function method1() {
  $('#table').find('input').each(function() {
    a = $(this).val()
    console.log(a)
  })
}

function method2() {
  $('#table').find('input').each((k,v) => {
    console.log(v.value)
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tbody id="dynamic_form_tbody">
    <tr id="1256">
      <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
      <td><input type="date" value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input onclick="method1()" type="button" value="method1">
<input onclick="method2()" type="button" value="method2">
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions (method 2) were introduced in ES6, which most modern browsers support (IE11 is one of the browsers does not support ES6).

One of the main differences is the **this** keyword. Quoting from this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp):

> In short, with arrow functions there are no binding of **this**.
>
> In regular functions the **this** keyword represented the object that called the function, which could be the window, the document, a button or whatever.
>
> With arrow functions the **this** keyword always represents the object that defined the arrow function.

Performance-wise, I don't think there is much of a difference, if at all.